# What happend to normal map?

Tags: texture-painting, normal-map

ive wanna recolor normal map to fix my problem with body but blender don't show any normal map

as you can see model in XPS had visible abs normal map
[image]

But model in blender normal map abs are not seen anywhere
[image]

Comment: go in the Node editor and plug the Normal map into the diffuse

Comment: not working i still see only diffuse in 3d view

Comment: may be caused by environment lightning (if light is homogeneous, no shadows)